# Closing the terminal doesnt remember my .profile changes for nvm/npm

Tags: node.js, npm, linux-mint

I installed nvm/npm using this instruction

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server (How To Install Using NVM), but everytime I close my terminal, it seems to forget all the settings and I have to do the command:
source ~/.profile then select the npm version to make it run again. How can I keep my settings permanent, or at least for the duration of my logged in session? Thanks! (linuxmint 17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sourcing ~/.profile

~/.profile is typically invoked from a login shell. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

> #### Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Opening a terminal does not typically invoke a login shell. Have you tried rebooting/relogging? Additionally if either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exist, then bash won't source `~/.profile`. There are two common ways to fix this:

#### Option 1

Move commands from the `~/.profile` file to `~/.bash_profile`

#### Option 2

Source `~/.profile` from `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -f ~/.profile ]] && . ~/.profile
```

### Default Node version

You can configure a default node version by aliasing it to `default`

> To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell, use the alias 'default':

```
nvm alias default node
```

See https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Hi Jonathan, same thing still happens. Should I just include it in the startup programs and add that command?

Comment: As per the bash docs quoted above, if you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` file then `~/.profile` won't be sourced.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more clarification on sourcing the `~/.profile` file.